# How to do with Quartz put some trigger to one job?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

```
public static void sendEmailForNewTrigger(String jobName, String triggerName, Date sendDate) {
    try {
        Scheduler sched = QuartzSchedulerManager.getInstanceScheduler();
        JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(jobName, "group_email");
        JobDetail job = sched.getJobDetail(jobKey);
        SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerName)
                .startAt(sendDate)
                .build();
        if (job == null) {
            job = newJob(SendEmailJob.class).withIdentity(jobName, "group_email").build();
        }
        sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        log.info(jobName + " will run at: " + sendDate);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

in my code ,it can't work, always tell me 'Unable to store Job : 'group_email.send_1', because one already exists with this identification.' i don't know how to do ,just want to add two or more trigger to one job.

Comment: group_email.send_1 already exists. Try to get the last element, add one to the number at the end, see what happens.

Comment: i want to use the same job, just change date to trigger

Comment: if you just want to change the trigger, use `rescheduleJob`. If you need to add a trigger in addition to the existing one(s), I think you can only get the triggers, remove the job, and schedule it again with the new set of triggers